# Nexus Start up really slow

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

We're running Sonatype Nexus 3 on an Odroid C1+, about equivalent to a RPi 2. Yes, not recommended, but for our development team of 2 performance is acceptable.

Except for Start-up. The Nexus 3 OSS Server takes an hour or more to be available.

Is that normal?
Any ideas why is is so slow?

Here are some of the log entries from a start-up.

```
2017-05-16 05:36:29,185+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer - $ANSI{green:italic OrientDB Server is active} v2.2.13.
2017-05-16 05:36:29,189+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl - Activated
2017-05-16 05:36:29,242+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager - Start UPGRADE
2017-05-16 05:36:35,919+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=config}} Storage 'config' was not closed properly. Will try to recover from write ahead log
2017-05-16 05:36:35,931+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=config}} Looking for last checkpoint...
2017-05-16 05:36:36,515+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=config}} Found FUZZY checkpoint.
2017-05-16 05:36:36,530+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=config}} Data restore procedure from FUZZY checkpoint is started.
2017-05-16 05:36:36,562+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=config}} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=6856901}} will be skipped during data restore
2017-05-16 05:36:36,570+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=config}} 1 operations were processed, current LSN is OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=6856901} last LSN is OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=6856954}
2017-05-16 05:36:36,579+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=config}} Record OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=6856908}} com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=null, previousCheckpoint=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=6856861}} will be skipped during data restore
2017-05-16 05:36:36,822+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=config}} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=6856948}} will be skipped during data restore
2017-05-16 05:36:36,829+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=config}} Storage data recover was completed
2017-05-16 05:42:54,800+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager - Start SCHEMAS
2017-05-16 05:42:55,883+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=analytics}} Storage 'analytics' was not closed properly. Will try to recover from write ahead log
2017-05-16 05:42:55,894+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=analytics}} Looking for last checkpoint...
2017-05-16 05:42:55,904+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=analytics}} Found FUZZY checkpoint.
2017-05-16 05:42:55,913+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=analytics}} Data restore procedure from FUZZY checkpoint is started.
2017-05-16 05:42:55,921+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=analytics}} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2246069}} will be skipped during data restore
2017-05-16 05:42:55,929+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=analytics}} 1 operations were processed, current LSN is OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2246069} last LSN is OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2246122}
2017-05-16 05:42:55,938+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=analytics}} Record OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2246076}} com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=null, previousCheckpoint=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2246029}} will be skipped during data restore
2017-05-16 05:42:55,946+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=analytics}} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2246116}} will be skipped during data restore
2017-05-16 05:42:55,952+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=analytics}} Storage data recover was completed
2017-05-16 05:49:05,078+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=audit}} Storage 'audit' was not closed properly. Will try to recover from write ahead log
2017-05-16 05:49:05,089+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=audit}} Looking for last checkpoint...
2017-05-16 05:49:05,097+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=audit}} Found FUZZY checkpoint.
2017-05-16 05:49:05,105+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=audit}} Data restore procedure from FUZZY checkpoint is started.
2017-05-16 05:49:05,113+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=audit}} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2268394}} will be skipped during data restore
2017-05-16 05:49:05,121+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=audit}} 1 operations were processed, current LSN is OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2268394} last LSN is OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2268447}
2017-05-16 05:49:05,129+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=audit}} Record OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2268401}} com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointStartRecord{lsn=null, previousCheckpoint=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2268354}} will be skipped during data restore
2017-05-16 05:49:05,138+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=audit}} Record com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OFuzzyCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=OLogSequenceNumber{segment=0, position=2268441}} will be skipped during data restore
2017-05-16 05:49:05,144+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage - $ANSI{green {db=audit}} Storage data recover was completed
```

Comment: It seems that the embedded orientdb was broken and it was auto recovered. Maybe you are doing something bad at shutdown?

Answer (score 3):

A few notes:

- This is cool! Someone on our internal team got it working on a Raspberry Pi 3 a while ago, so we love seeing stuff like this
- We don't support this configuration so any help from us is kinda on a "wow this is cool" sort of level

Our internal dude said he noticed that NXRM 3 runs out of memory while updating schemas during boot on the Raspberry Pi 3, <del>and he's yet to find a workaround.</del>

He found a workaround. He's got a great big beard, too. He edited nexus.vmoptions to have the following:

`-Xms256M
-Xmx256M
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512M`

Orient uses system memory, which is distinct from Nexus Repo which uses the Java Heap, if that helps you at all. The note above about Orient and shutdown is also probably very wildly relevant.

Here's some info we put together about Orient and memory, and tuning:

[Optimizing OrientDB Database Memory](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007093447-Optimizing-OrientDB-Database-Memory-)

Also here is a more generic article on system requirements in regards to Nexus Repository Manager 3:

[Nexus Repository Manager 3 System Requirements](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006448847?flash_digest=37712ffaa2f58d94d33d9e6dd52a48c7e1ca4103)

What I would suggest for your team is wildly different, potentially use our Docker image and spin Nexus Repo up on whatever hardware you've got to use.

[Docker Nexus3](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/)

Best luck either way!

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I neglected to mention that we'd used the Docker install. Also, yes the server was probably brutally terminated by either a power off or a linux "reboot"

Comment: Made the changes to vmoptions as suggested, then tried by shutting down and restarting the Docker container. Nexus still took a long time to start. How should I shut down Nexus 3/OrientDB gracefully?